# Subset dataframe based on values in one column of preceeding rows

Tags: pandas

I originally asked this question here [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71162672/isolate-events-from-either-an-array-or-dataframe) but it has had no views as yet!
I will try and express it better.

I have a dataframe of rain amounts at various gauges over time.

I want to extract the rain events based on the incidence of no rain at one gauge.

When this gauge records a reading after a set number of zero values, this constitutes the start of an event.

When it reads another set number of zeros this is the end of the event.

I want to extract the block of rows between the start and end.

I posted data in the original question, I can't write code to generate the df, as it is original data.

Comment: I have added a comment to your original question.

Comment: I have responded to your comment